# How to update y-axis in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have problem update limits on `y-axis`.
My idea is to read some csv file, and to plot some graphs.
When I set limits for `y-axis`, it doesn't show on the plot.
It always shows, values from file.

I'm new in python.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
import numpy as np

x = []
y = []
chamber_temperature = []

with open(r"C:\Users\mm02058\Documents\test.txt", 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter = '\t')

    for row in (reader):
        x.append(row[0])
        chamber_temperature.append(row[1])
        y.append(row[10])

x.pop(0)
y.pop(0)
chamber_temperature.pop(0)
#print(chamber_temperature)

arr = np.array(chamber_temperature)
n_lines = len(arr)
time = np.arange(0,n_lines,1)
time_sec = time * 30
time_min = time_sec / 60
time_hour = time_min / 60
time_day = time_hour / 24

Fig_1 = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8), dpi=100)
plt.suptitle("Powered Thermal Cycle", fontsize=14, x=0.56, y= 0.91)

plt.subplot(311, xlim=(0, 30), ylim=(-45,90), xticks=(0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30), yticks=( -40, -30, -20, -10, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90), ylabel=("Temperature [°C]"))
plt.plot(time_hour, chamber_temperature, 'k', label='Temperature')
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.grid()
plt.legend(shadow=True, fontsize=('small'), loc = 'center right', bbox_to_anchor=(1.13, 0.5))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some examples of your CSV file?

Comment: file is to big, so i upload just one part of the file.

Comment: sorry, i.m not sure how to upload file to this portal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks suspicious, because I cannot see a conversion from strings (what `csv.reader` produces) to floating point numbers.

Also your plot look suspicious, because the *y* tick labels are not sorted!

I decided to check if, by chance, Matplotlib tries to be smarter than it should...

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# let's plot an array of strings, as I suppose you did,
# and see if Matplotlib doesn't like it, or ...

np.random.seed(20210719)
arr_of_floats = 80+10*np.random.rand(10)
arr_of_strings = np.array(["x = %6.3f"%round(x, 2) for x in arr_of_floats])
plt.plot(range(10), arr_of_strings)
plt.show()
```

[image: the wrong plot]

Now, let's see what happens if we perform the conversion to floats

```
# for you it's simply: array(chamber_temperature, dtype=float)
arr_of_floats = np.array([s[4:] for s in arr_of_strings], dtype=float)
plt.plot(range(10), arr_of_floats)
plt.show()
```

[image: the correct plot]

Eventually, do not change axes' limits (etc etc) BEFORE plotting, but:

- first, possibly organize your figure (figure size, subplots, etc)
- second, plot your data,
- third, adjust the details of the graph and
- fourth and last, commit your work using `plt.show()`.

Comment: You have right.
Python read values from file as strings. When i convert them to float, i get y-axes with wanted limits.
Thanks a lot for help....

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
plt.ylim([bottom limit, top limit]) #like plt.ylim(84,86)
```

before your

```
plt.show()
```

that should work!

You are setting your x and y lims, as you have the equal sign.
You need to call them like a function (no equal sign).

Comment: perhaps try removing the xlim=(0, 30) & ylim=(-45,90) from the line

```plt.subplot(311, xlim=(0, 30), ylim=(-45,90), xticks=(0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30), yticks=( -40, -30, -20, -10, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90), ylabel=("Temperature [°C]"))```